# COALESCE not working?

Tags: sql, coalesce

I have NULLS in my P.EMP_PAY_DUE_TO_LEAVE_DATE field and I've tried eliminating them by using the following bit of code but the NULLS remain!

```
SELECT DISTINCT V.EMP_CODE
, CASE 
    WHEN V.HIST_PERIOD < 10 
    THEN 
        CAST(V.HIST_YEAR AS VARCHAR)     + RIGHT('0' + CAST (V.HIST_PERIOD + 3 AS VARCHAR), 2) 
    ELSE 
        CAST(V.HIST_YEAR + 1 AS VARCHAR) + RIGHT('0' + CAST (V.HIST_PERIOD - 9 AS VARCHAR) ,2) 
  END AS PAYPERIOD
, V.Department_Id
, CASE 
    WHEN MONTH (P.EMP_PAY_DUE_TO_LEAVE_DATE) >= MONTH(DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE()) 
    OR P.EMP_PAY_DUE_TO_LEAVE_DATE IS NULL 
    THEN 
        COALESCE
        (
            CONVERT
            (
                DECIMAL(10, 2)
                , V.EMP_SORT_DESC
            )
            , 0
        ) / 37.5
    END AS FTE
```

I can't see anything wrong with my code but clearly there is!  Can anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last...

```
CASE
  WHEN (MONTH (P.EMP_PAY_DUE_TO_LEAVE_DATE) >= MONTH(DATEADD(M, -1, GETDATE())) OR P.EMP_PAY_DUE_TO_LEAVE_DATE IS NULL) 
    THEN (COALESCE (CONVERT (DECIMAL (10, 2) ,V.EMP_SORT_DESC), 0) / 37.5) END AS FTE
```

does not have an `ELSE` case, which implicity becomes `NULL` if the `THEN` case doesn't apply.

Comment: FYI: I reformatted the code to make it simpler to read / in doing so made the implicit else explicit - but commented it so it's clear it wasn't in the original code.

Comment: @JohnLBevan - You shouldn't make edits that invalidate existing answers. I've removed the `ELSE` so this answer still makes sense.

Comment: @MartinSmith: Agreed.  FYI: I made the edit before the answer existed / just to make the code more readable for myself & others before answering; since the questioner had said the issue was with the coalesce it didn't occur to me that the case would be the issue until after I'd made the edit and seen it in context.

Comment: @JohnLBevan No harm done! Just a bit odd to have an answer saying there is no `ELSE` when the question contains one!